# Lubuntu, wifi's displayed but connection times out

Tags: drivers, wireless, lubuntu

A solve is published for a different person/laptop ie

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install firmware-b43-installer
```

did not work for me.  I have a HP 250-G3. I have the following info that may assist (below ).  Does anyone know if I have the wrong driver and how I can install that?

```
  configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:90700000-907fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
                vendor: Ralink corp.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
                logical name: wlp2s0f0
                version: 00
                serial: c0:38:96:87:65:33
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800pci driverversion=4.4.0-21-generic firmware=0.37 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
```

Comment: please edit your question and add the output of the wifi-script: https://askubuntu.com/a/425205/669014

Comment: how do I do that ?

Comment: Below your question you have a tiny gray *edit* button/link to click on, if you want to edit your posting. Than you just copy the whole output of that *wireless-info-script* from the inside of your terminal and paste it here, inside the <pre> tags. Another solution would be to post the whole output at https://pastebin.com/ and leave a link in here.